# Scheme function for building list of even integers

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I am trying to write a function in Scheme that takes a list as an argument and returns a list containing only the even integers from the argument list. After working through the problem, this is what I have come up with:

```
(define (even-list n)
    (if (even? car(n))
        (cons car(n) even-list(cdr(n)))
        (even-list cdr(n))
    )
)
```

To test my function `even-list` I have built a small list to pass as the argument to the function. However, when I run the code below, all that happens is that the list is outputted:

```
even-list (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

It almost seems like it isn't even calling the function, as I replaced the `then` clause with `"even"` and `"even"` was never outputted. Any ideas?

Comment: that's not valid scheme/racket... fix syntax errors before posting questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that scheme/racket uses [prefix](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Polish_notation) notation, whereby any procedure being applied gets wrapped around opening and closing brackets `(function-name arg1 arg2 ...)`.

This means that `car(n)`, `cdr(n)`, `even-list(...)` etc. are invalid syntax, and should be replaced with `(car n)`, `(cdr n)`, `(even-list ...)` etc. respectively.

This is also why you are not seeing any changes in output when making modifications to your procedure `even-list`, because with simply writing

```
even-list (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

you are calling an identifier (`even-list`) which may/may not be bound (in this case it is bound with the function definition), and the expression `(list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)`. This expression is what is returning your list output, and any changes you make within `even-list` will not be reflected on this list, since you have not actually passed it as an argument to a procedure, but rather simply applied it using the `list` built-in procedure.

Once you fix the line to:

```
(even-list (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
```

you will start to notice errors that stem from your procedure logic. For example, your [recursive](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Recursion) function has no base case, meaning that as the function recurses through the list, when it reaches a list of zero elements `'()`, it still attemps to apply `(car n)`, which is a contract violation on `car` since it is expecting a `pair?` for an argument.

Consider the following:

```
(define (even-list lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lst) empty)                           ; base case (empty? list)
    ((even? (car lst))                            ; even? first element
     (cons (car lst) (even-list (cdr lst))))   
    (else (even-list (cdr lst)))))
```

or, using built-in [`filter`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=filter#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29) procedure:

```
(define (even-list lst)
  (filter even? lst))
```